# How to search by category in magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I want to search data acccording to category but it is not searched by category.There is one category dropdown section and a search box in header and i want to search keyword according to selected category. but it is not searching by category.

I used code in `app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/template/catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml` page

```
<?php
$catalogSearchHelper =  $this->helper('catalogsearch');
 $cats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category') -> load(2) -> getChildren();
    $catIds = explode(',', $cats);
    $categories = array();
    foreach ($catIds as $catId) {
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category') -> load($catId);
        $categories[$category -> getName()] = array('name' => $category -> getName(), 'url' => $category -> getUrl(), 'img' => $category -> getImageUrl(), 'subcategories' => Mage::getModel('catalog/category') -> getCategories($catId));
    }
    ksort($categories, SORT_STRING);
?>
<form id="search_mini_form" action="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getResultUrl() ?>" method="get">
 <div class="wrapper-demo">
  <div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-3" tabindex="1">
                        <span>All Categories</span>
                        <ul class="dropdown content">
                            <?php foreach($categories as $name => $data): ?>
        <li><a><?php echo $data['name']; ?></a>
            </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
    </div>
        <input id="search" type="search" placeholder="Enter your keyword" name="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getQueryParamName() ?>" value="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getEscapedQueryText() ?>" maxlength="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getMaxQueryLength();?>" />
        <input type="image" name="myclicker" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/searchicon.png'); ?>" > 

        <div id="search_autocomplete" class="search-autocomplete"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
            var searchForm = new Varien.searchForm('search_mini_form', 'search', '<?php echo $this->__('Search entire store here...') ?>');
            searchForm.initAutocomplete('<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getSuggestUrl() ?>', 'search_autocomplete');
        //]]>
        </script>
</form>
```

If anyone know it, then please help me out.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

[Catalog Category Search Plugin](http://www.geekyplugins.com/magento/catalog-category-search.dot)